# Can i make a PDF file abvailable offline on a reactjs PWA?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, offline, offline-caching

I am starting my first PWA project using react.js and I am wondering it its possible to make a PDF file available offline using PWA. I am not sure of the files sizes yet but i believe it wont take more than 500Mb of space. if not is there a way to download the files into the catch and then make it offline?

Answer (score 2):

There's file system access API, but [adoption is very limited](https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api).

See https://web.dev/file-system-access/

Comment: It cant run on IOS which might cause a problem.. but thank you for the suggestion. learnt something new.